# How to get filename from resource (itemReader) in Spring batch?

Tags: java, spring

I want to get the value of resource item Reader (input/file1.xml) and use it in another simple class which prints the name of this file.

spring batch

```
<bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">

    <property name="resource"
        value="classpath:input/file1.xml" />

    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="Users" />

    <property name="unmarshaller">
        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
            <property name="classesToBeBound">
                <list>
                    <value>com.pon.USER</value>


                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a bean of type Resource and inject it on your item Reader (throw a *ref* and not a *value*) and on your class bean